# « prévenir » en comparaison avec « avertir »

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

Les mots *prévenir* et *avertir* peuvent se remplacer parfois, mais n’ont pas entièrement le même sens. Je cherche à décrire comment les mots sont apparentés et qu’est-ce qu’ils n’ont pas en commun.

Je pensais que l’on utilise prévenir quand il y a quelque chose que quelqu’un ne sait pas encore. « Prévenir quelqu’un » est alors le mettre au courant. On prévient quelqu’un quand quelque chose ne se passe pas comme prévu, par exemple un feu qui se répand. Ceux qui sont *prévenus* sont souvent des personnes puissantes, comme une équipe de sapeurs-pompiers -pour le même exemple-. Ils savent maitriser des incendies, .

Quant à *avertir*, je crois plutôt qu’on utilise ce mot quand quelqu’un se comporte mal, et il se fait tapé sur les doigts pour corriger cet écart de tenue. Si j’ai bien compris ce mot, il s'agit de quelqu’un qui sait qu’il enfreint les règles. Il reçoit un avertissement de quelqu’un qu’il se doit d'écouter, sinon on lui inflige une peine. Les peines viennent de personnes qui sont plus puissantes par rapport au puni, et qui jouissent du droit de punir.

Quel est votre avis ?

Comment: @Mina, Je peux voir que vous réécrivez des choses de manière plus approfondie. Merci =D. 
Il est néanmoins dur de comprendre tout ce que vous avez ajusté.
Ce serait gentil si vous pouvez éclairer un changement : Pouvez-vous m’expliquer pourquoi vous avez remplacé « devoir » par « se devoir de » ?

Comment: Il faut d’ailleurs dire que « ne se passe pas comme prévu » n’est pas vraiment ce que je voulais exprimer. Avec « aller à l’envers », je voulais plutôt dire « aller de bien en mal ». J’avoue que je ne savais pas si ce mot serait convenable ici, à vrai dire je l’ai mis à l’essai cette tournure. Heureusement j’ai découvert qu’elle n’est pas convenable ici.

Comment: Après avoir consulté la définition du verbe _se devoir_ sur [l'office québécois de la langue française](http://66.46.185.79/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2441) et qui dit 'Précédant un verbe à l’infinitif, se devoir décrit une obligation morale, un devoir que l’on a en vertu de ses principes, de ses valeurs, de ses fonctions ou de sa mission.' Je pense que je n'aurais pas dû faire cette modification. Vôtre tournure était la plus juste.

Comment: Quant à « aller de bien en mal », désolée de n'avoir pas compris ce à quoi  vous faisiez allusion. Pour l'instant, je ne vois d'expression qui exprime cela exactement.

Comment: Je veux ajouter que quelque soit les changements que j'ai apporté a cette question, ce ne sont que des stipulations de ma part. La question reste vôtre et vous avez parfaitement le droit de la réediter si vous pensez(comme pour « aller de bien en mal ») que ça ne reflète pas ce que vous vouliez dire à l'initial, même si votre expression initiale n'est pas des plus _idiomatiques_

Comment: Je vous remercie pour ce que vous avez fait quand même. La plupart de corrigeurs n’enlèvent que les fautes qui sont les plus moches, (parce qu’ils craignent qu’ils changent des choses à tort), et laissent des phrases tordues de côté. Tant mieux qu’il y a des gens qui m’aident à rafistoler mon français de contrebande en ôtant des morceaux qui vont mal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17311/discussion-between-mina-and-koenraad-van-duin).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Prévenir** : dans le sens de *venir avant* : *Précéder, devancer* :

> Celui-ci l'avait prévenu en se réfugiant de lui-même au monastère de Cluny (Michelet)

Ici c'est le danger que l'homme réfugié au monastère a vu venir, il a donc 'pré-vu' (vu avant qu'il n'apparaisse réellement) le danger et l'ayant 'vu' *venir*, il a pu l'éviter.

> *Prévenir* les besoins de quelqu'un.

*Venir* et donc agir avant que le besoin se fasse sentir, et donc *devancer* (*avancer* dans le temps, ou aller *au-devant* dans l'espace) l'action qui va répondre au besoin prévisible.

> Moyens de prévenir les maladies.

*Détourner, éviter* que la maladie arrive, ici l'action est faite avant que le besoin se manifeste : on prévient les épidémies par la vaccination : quand on vaccine, il n'y a pas de maladie.

De même *"Prévenir* une objection : la réfuter avant qu'elle ait été formulée."

---

*Prévenir* dans le sens d'**avertir**  (il peut le remplacer dans les phrases suivantes) : *aviser, influencer, mettre au courant, informer, instruire* :

> Je l'ai *prévenu* de votre visite.

Je l'ai *averti* de ....

> Des mauvaises langues vous ont *prévenu* contre lui.

Vous ont *influencé*, vous ont 'monté contre' lui.

> Ne fais rien sans me *prévenir.*

*Avertis-moi* avant d'agir.

> « Prévenez-moi si vous avez d'autres cas » dit Rieux. (Camus)

*Informez-moi* si ...

> Tu es *prévenu* : si tu recommences, tu seras puni !

Tu es maintenant *instruit* (au sens juridique du terme), tu connais les règles, la Loi ; tu es *averti*.

> Les gendarmes sont *prévenus*, ils vont vous arrêter.

Les gendarmes sont *informés* ...

---

<sup>Références et exemples tirés du Robert</sup>

Comment: Je lis ici que ces mots chevauchent plus que ce à quoi je m’attendais. Merci pour la réponse lucide.

Comment: I infer that "prévenir" and "avertir" are identical when they mean "to warn" ?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista — Exactement, quand vous tapez *warn* dans https://www.deepl.com/translator#en/fr/%22to%20warn%22 vous avez ces deux réponses.